# Eclipse - open a new browser tab?

Tags: java, eclipse

how can I open a new browser tab/windows within eclipse?
I is launched if I make a deploy to a server. But what if I don't? How can I launch one?

tyvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to open an internal browser:

```
Menu -> Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Internal Web Browser
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to open as a new tab (for convenience). because do by your way, it will open as a new window. Thanks :)

Comment: I did it like that and it jumped to the already opened browser :c